# A word for stripping someone of something hard-earned

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

It is like taking away the fame, wealth or influence of a celebrity.

The police ____ Alan Turing. 
Alan Turing was unfortunately ____.

Comment: Look up **deplume**.

Comment: [Degrade](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/degrade).

Comment: [Synonyms of degrade](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/degrade).

Comment: @HotLicks Maybe op is looking for the opposite of deify/idolize/iconize.

Comment: @vickyace - Yep, one can take any number of words and look at their synonyms or antonyms to find candidate words in a situation like this.  All it takes is a little research, which the OP has not done.

Comment: @HotLicks Exactly. There isn't a word for everything yet.

Comment: It's too broad, do you want a verb that means exactly to intentionally remove someone's  fame, money, and good name? Or how someone's [reputation lies in tatters](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tatters) because of bad press/publicity/decisions, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Defrock](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defrock) is a good option.

The second sense from Merriam-Webster reads:

> to remove from a position of honor or privilege.

Comment: The "frock" in the term "defrock" refers to the robes traditionally worn by Christian clergy. The more narrow definition is to remove someone from church ministry or office by metaphorically or literally tearing their robes off, which is usually done in response to heresy, apostasy, or scandalous public sinning such as being caught in adultery. By further metaphorical extension, it can be used to mean to strip anyone of an office of power.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [**dispossessed**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dispossess)?

> to take land, possessions, etc., from (someone)

Depending on the situation, **[crucified](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crucify)** may work as well.

> to destroy the power of

Answer (score 2):

*"The police **discredited** Alan Turing. Alan Turing was unfortunately **discredited**."*

**Discredit** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/discredit)

> *verb* 1. Harm the good reputation of:
>   *"his remarks were taken out of context in an effort to discredit him"*

Relevant article: [The Story of Alan Turing - Pioneer in Mathematics, Computer Science and Homosexuality](http://www.documentarytube.com/articles/the-story-of-alan-turing--pioner-in-mathematics-computer-science-and-homosexuality)

> In 1952, Turing wrote to his friend and mathematician Norman Routledge, revealing that he was afraid that he will be **discredited** and his ideas will be **discredited** because of him publically confessing he had sex with another man. Back in the days, homosexuality was considered a criminal act in Britain.

Answer (score 1):

To ***[deprive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deprive):***

> - to remove or withhold something from the enjoyment or possession of (a person or persons):
>     *to deprive a man of life*.

Dictionary.com

Comment: I would have to add a lot of things after *deprive*. This is way too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Defame

> de·fame  (dĭ-fām′)
>   tr.v. de·famed, de·fam·ing, de·fames
>
> 1. To damage the reputation, character, or good name of (someone) by slander or libel. See Synonyms at malign.
> 2. Archaic To disgrace.

The Free Dictionary by Farlex